# Nginx with Phusion Passenger URI routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, reverse-proxy

This is my Nginx Server config file

```
server {
        listen   80;
        location /node {
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                include         /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        }
        location /ror {
                root /var/www/ror/public;
                passenger_enabled on;
                proxy_cache        off;
                proxy_pass_header  Server;
        }
        location / {
                root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        }
}
```

This is mostly a 'HelloWorld' setup to test running Node and RoR simultaneously for a REST server.

The issue is that I need to have `servername.com/ror` forward to `/var/www/ror/public`, inorder for RoR to respond.  I have tried a few configurations, and cannot figure out how to get it to forward correctly.  The issue seems to be that the `ror` URI segment gets passed on to RoR, which causes it to look for that controller, which returns a 404.

The other configuration, changing root to `/var/www` works as long as I include `/ror/public` in the URI.

So, is there a way to perform the sub URI routing on the reverse proxy in this manner?

---

Ok, so I added the rewrite rule.

```
location /ror {
        root /var/www/ror/public;
        rewrite ^/ror/(.*)$ /$1 last;
        passenger_enabled on;
        proxy_cache        off;
        proxy_pass_header  Server;
}
```

The issue, however, is that now it is serving files from the default root, which in my install is `/usr/nginx` and is completely ignoring the root inside the location block.

**I appreciate the help.  This is my first time with Nginx (Typically an Apache Fiend), so I'm having trouble wrapping my head how it's interpreting these commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out.

My VHOST Section:

```
server {
        #server_name domain.com;
        listen   80;
        root /var/www/rails;

        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_base_uri /todo;

        rails_spawn_method smart;
        rails_env development;

        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_pass_header Server;

        location /node {
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                include         /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        }
}
```

I ended up creating a new directory called rails, and inside of that I created a symbolic link to the public directory of the actual application.

```
ln -s /var/www/todo/public /var/www/rails/todo
```

Also, I was not initializing Passenger correctly, which is why it was not responding and giving back errors.  This setup is not ideal, considering I now have to manually add each sub URI application, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

`/ror/a.txt` is `/var/www/ror/public/ror/a.txt` in local fs, so you need to use rewrite rule in `location /ror`.

Like `rewrite ^/ror(.*)$ $1;`